# Is a function that run Async functions considered Async itself? And how to handle its errors?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

so I have a function that runs some other async functions, And I would like to know what would be the best way to handle its errors, and if I'm doing it "the right way".

Basically what this function does is:

1. Receive a "Model Name", an object with properties to be passed to the Schema and a Callback function(which I don't know if I need, or is best practice in this situation).
2. Then I check the inputs(look at the comments), in one case I use the filesystem module(Async) because I want to require the model only if it is needed.
3. And after that, I try to save it all to the database, which is async as well.

Quick note: I'm using Mongoose to handle the database.

/*
* Function for adding new entries to the database.
* This function depends on various asynchronous functions,
* so we expect to receive a callback function for better error handling.
*
* Expects:
*   modelName = name of the model to be used.
*   properties = an object to pass to the model's schema.
*   callback = explained above.
*/
function add(modelName, properties, callback) {

```
// If a callback wasn't passed, throw error.
if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
    return callback(new Error('Model Add function should receive a callback'));
}

/*
* The variable 'properties' is not required, so only if declared
* we'll check if it is an object.
* IMPORTANT: Needs to be fixed!
*/
if (typeof properties !== 'object') {
    return callback(new Error('Properties passed should be an Object'));
}

/*
* Checking modelName is an existing model by checking if a file with that
* name exists in the models directory.
*
* This is an asynchronous so we handle the output(which can result in an error)
* using a callback.
*/
fs.access(`./models/${modelName.toLowerCase()}.js`, fs.constants.F_OK, err => {

    // If an error is returned it means that the file does not exists.
    if (err) {
        return callback(new Error(`There is no Model "${modelName}"`));
    }

    // Require the model file.
    require(`./${modelName.toLowerCase()}`);

    // Getting the model.
    let Model = mongoose.model(modelName);
    let document = new Model(properties);

    // Saving the new "document" to the database.
    document.save(err => {
        if (err) {
            return callback(new Error(`Error while saving "${modelName}" to the Database: ${err}`));
        }

        // For debugging purposes...
        console.log(`A new ${modelName} was successfully saved to the database`);
    });

});
```

}

As you can see, I have here nested Async functions, and I feel like it could be done a better way.

Any ideas? is this the right way to handle database tasks?

Thanks Ahead!

Comment: Just  by curiosity, do you use this on a server (with express for example) and do you execute this function on every request? If yes, accessing the file system and requiring modules per request it is going to have a huge impact on the performance. Also, there is an inconsistency on the error handling. In one case you are throwing an exception that will crash the program and in another you are returning the error in the callback. I think that it worth taking a look here about the error handling:
[error handling](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html)

Comment: As Svabael writes, this could be a huge issue. I don't understand, why generate models on fly? Im curious. If you need to create custom models based on user activity, based on this you are missing the point of having a NoSQL database.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I don't use this on a live server or anything, I'm just trying to build a small project to get better. About the errors - I was checking what was the best way, but I updated the code above to what I currently use, but I'm still looking for the "right way" to handle those errors. And this function will be run when I want to add something to the database, for example, a "post" or something similar. will it be better for performance to require all the models ahead?

Comment: I'm not generating models on the fly, but i might have many, so i thought that it would be cleaner to get them only when needed :) I guess i learned that it's a terrible mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Few things I noticed:

```
if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
    return callback(new Error('Model Add function should receive a callback'));
}
```

How do you expect to call a callback saying that there was no callback?

```
// Require the model file.
require(`./${modelName.toLowerCase()}`);
```

`require()` is **synchronous** - never call it inside an asynchronous function. It may get cached and would block only on its first invocation (for every model) but it will block your entire server nonetheless.

In any case, this question may be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Didn't thought of that... Should i throw an exception in this case?